# HTML/DOM: Selecting a specific class in multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have this personal homework. I want to reimplement getElementsByClassName(). I am using jQuery-append to add paragraph tags with either 1 class or few classes.

My issue:
I am using className or getAttribute to see if it has a class. If so, as long as it contains "targetHello" class, push that paragraph element into an array. Trying to do this without using RegExp.

For example,

```
class="hello1 targetHello hello3"
```

Thanks!

Comment: How far did you get with your own solution, what went wrong? Why are you '*trying to do this without using RegExp*'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With that function, you could get false positives. For instance, it will return true if the value of the attribute class is "hello1targetHellohello3", and this one doesn't contain the class you are looking for. You should identify the isolate word remembering that the classes are words separated by blank spaces. For instance:

```
function hasClassName(classNames, className) {
    return classNames.split(' ').indexOf(className) >= 0;
}

var classValue = 'hello1 targetHello hello3';

hasClassName(classValue, 'targetHello');
```

In any case, I think I misunderstood something... you are using jQuery to append content, and I don't understand why you are not using it also to get the elements with the class you want. I guess it is a kind of practice or something, right?

Comment: Definitely to practice and what is happening under the hood. It really helps me learn in great detail! Thank you so much for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` and check the `length` like this.

```
function hasClassName(classNames, className) {
    return classNames.split(className).length > 1;
}

var classNames = "hello1 targetHello hello3";

hasClassName(classNames, 'targetHello');
```

If `classNames.split(className).length` is `1` then the class does not exist. If it is greater than `1` then it exists.